# Is Falling Bash actually better than Jump Slash for mounting?

Tags: monster-hunter-rise

Mounting a monster has undergone a major revamp in *MONSTER HUNTER RISE*, and so has the Sword and Shield's moveset. In it, Falling Bash is now treated as an aerial move and can be used to mount a monster.

So, does it mean now the jumping slash is obsolete? Damage of Jump Slash is pathetic compared to Falling Bash. Does it mean the Falling Bash is actually better in all aspects, especially mounting since it is significantly stronger than the jumping slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my playtime with S&S, I'd agree that Falling Bash is almost a straight upgrade over Jump Slash. The only difference is that Falling Bash inflicts blunt damage while Jump Slash inflicts slashing damage, meaning that if you want to cut a monster's tail off or just use slashing on a body part where blunt isn't effective, you'll want to switch to Jump Slash.